Indexing in AWS Dynamo DB
How can I create an index for this scenario? The table consists of columns: OrderId, FromDate, ToDate, and HistoricalData. I need to use the first three columns to upsert data into the HistoricalData column and also to retrieve the data. Should I use an LSI or a GSI?

You don't state what your access patterns are so it's hard to help.
If you really need strong consistency, and just different sort order for your data then you can use an LSI, but you cannot add one to an existing table.
A much better solution is using a GSI to a table to achieve more flexible querying. You can add and delete it at any time. GSIs are eventually consistent only, should that matter.

Access patterns include retrieving HistoricalData using OrderId, FromDate, and ToDate.

You need to manually combine those values into a combination of partition and sort key for your index. And use a GSI

I need to set OrderId as the partition key and use a combination of FromDate and ToDate as the sort key in a GSI. Is this correct?

No you can only use one of the dates. If you need a from data and to date, then one is your sort key and the other becomes a value that you filter on.
